# how to change test Stripe payments to live Stripe payments in react native

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe for   payments for my app. I was able to configure to take test payments, which are appearing on my Stripe dashboard. I have now changed the stripe test keys in my code and swapped them out with live keys. However when I make a payment, the payment still shows up as a test mode payment. it even shows a test mode credit card number and not the credit card number that was used to make the live payment.
How do I get my stripe payment to show an actual live payment?

Here is my backend code
i'm using firebase functions.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_live XXXXX')
exports.completePaymentWithStripe = functions.https.onRequest((request,response)=>{
    stripe.charges.create({
        amount: request.body.amount,
        currency: request.body.currency,
        source: request.body.token.tokenId
    })
    .then(charge => {
        response.send(charge);
        return null
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
)
```

and here is my payment function that calls to the stripe api

```
stripe.setOptions({
    publishableKey: "pk_live_XXX "
})

const onPaymentPress = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const { user = {}} = route.params;
        const { firstName = "", lastName = "" } = user
        const expMonth = Number(expDate.split("/")[0])
        const expYear = Number(expDate.split("/")[1])
        const params = {
            number: ccNumber,
            expMonth: expMonth,
            expYear: expYear,
            cvc: cvv,
            currency: 'usd',
            name: '',
            addressLine1: '',
            addressLine2: '',
            addressCity: '',
            addressState: '',
            addressCountry: '',
            addressZip: '',
        };
        const token = await stripe.createTokenWithCard(params).catch(err => {
            setLoading(false);
            alert(err);
        })
        if (!token) return;

        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "https://us-central1-lvc2-73300.cloudfunctions.net/completePaymentWithStripe",
            data: {
                amount: 100,
                currency: 'usd',
                name: firstName + " " + lastName,
                token: token
            }
        }).then(response => {
            alert("Payment Successful");
            
            setLoading(false);
            updateFirebase(response.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            setLoading(false);
            console.log("err ", err);
            alert(JSON.stringify(err.message));
        })
    }

    updateFirebase = (stripeResponse) => {
        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        const uid = user.uid
        const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
        usersRef
            .doc(uid)
            .set({ "subscribed": true }, { merge: true })
            .then(async () => {
                console.log("Success");
                const { id, amount, paid, receipt_url } = stripeResponse;
                const data = { 
                    userId: uid, 
                    stripe_payment_id: id, 
                    amount, paid, receipt_url,
                    created: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
                };
```

Comment: you might have to debug more and see a) if your Firebase function with the live keys was actually deployed and b) if your ReactNative app is indeed using your live mode key. If you swap out to live mode keys, all requests should occur in live mode on your Stripe dashboard, so try breaking down the problem and looking at it step by step (i.e. are you even getting a single request made in live mode on the Stripe Dashboard?